# Virtual functions and default parameters

Tags: c++, overriding

Lets say I have a class A, B and C

```
class A{
    public:
        virtual void f4(){
            cerr<<"A::f4()"<<endl;
        }
};


class B: public A{
    public: 
        virtual void f4(int n){
            cerr<<"B::f4("<<n<<")"<<endl;
        }
};

class C: public B{
    public:
        virtual void f4(int n = 1){
            cerr<<"C::f4("<<n<<")"<<endl;
        }
};
```

If I have:

```
C c;
A& rac = c;
rac.f4();
```

I was expecting c's version of f4 to be called but that's not what happens. Can someone explain?

Comment: Did you mean to have another `}` after the line `cerr << "B::f4"`... ?

Comment: yes, edited the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compiling [with clang -Wall](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f798808a033cb1bd) the following warnings occur:

```
main.cpp:14:22: warning: 'B::f4' hides overloaded virtual function [-Woverloaded-virtual]
    virtual void f4(int n){
                 ^
main.cpp:6:22: note: hidden overloaded virtual function 'A::f4' declared here: different number of parameters (0 vs 1)
    virtual void f4(){
                 ^
```

These warnings explain what's going on.  A virtual function is only overridden by another function with the same signature.

`B::f4(int)` does not override `A::f4()` because they have different parameter lists. Instead, it is a different virtual function.

So `rac.f4()` just calls `A::f4()` which is not overridden.

Since C++11 you can help to detect this problem:

```
virtual void f4(int n) override {
//                     ^^^^^^^^
```

Then the compiler will give an error if this function does not actually override something from the base.

Answer (score 2):

Because the signatures of f4 don't match between A and B/C classes.

This is A's function signature for f4:

```
void A::f4()  // no parameters
```

B and C use this function signature

```
void B::f4(int n)
```

If you are doing to override a method, it needs to have the same return type and identical parameter list. Otherwise, even if the method in the derived class has the same name as the parent class, C++ will don't consider that an override.

FWIW, `C::f4` does override `B::f4`.  The default parameter you introduce on `class C` doesn't influence the virtual methods override behavior.  And this is the exact reason why, on my team, we disallow overloading methods with different signatures and banning default parameters. Because it leads to bugs like this.

Here's C's v-table (the methods available on it):

```
void C::f4(); // no parameters, overrides A::f4()
void C::f4(int n);  // overrides B::f4()
```

Comment: Because C inherits from B it must use that form?

Comment: C has two methods named f4.  One that is inherited from A (via B) named `void f4()` and another that is inherited from B named `void f4(int)`

Comment: If you had implemented `void C::f4(int x)` with no default parameter values, you would have overriden A's implementation.  But as you have it, you are overriding B's implementation of a *different method name*.

Comment: @selbie `C::f4(int x)` and `C::f4(int x = 1)` are identical signatures and they both override `B::f4`.  The `A::f4` had no parameters. Also "different method name" is not the best description, since the methods all have the same name `f4`. "different signature" is the official term.